# How can I pass additional data to panResponder (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, animation, drag-and-drop, components

I am working on a project, where I have multiple `<Image />` components but I'm running into an issue where I can not indicate which image the user is grabbing, at any given time. My first thought to work around this issue was to wrap the image in a `TouchableOpacity`, an onPress function would fire and pass down the data of the image to update the state (`this.setState({ currentImage: imageData })`). But this doesn't work with `panResponder`. So my question is, 
is there any way pass down data to panResponder or how can I let the panResponder which image the user is grabbing?

```
class App extends React.Component {

  point = new Animated.ValueXY();

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      shapesArr: [],
      isGrabbing: false,
      currentShape: {},
    };
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.log(findNodeHandle(evt.nativeEvent.target));
        this.setState({ isGrabbing: true });
        Animated.event([{ x: this.point.x }])({ x: gestureState.x0 - 21 })
        Animated.event([{ y: this.point.y }])({ y: gestureState.y0  - 21})

        // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
        // what is happening!
        // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // console.log(gestureState);
        Animated.event([{ y: this.point.y }])({ y: gestureState.moveY - 21 })
        Animated.event([{ x: this.point.x }])({ x: gestureState.moveX - 21 })
        // Animated.event([{ x: this.point.x }])({ x: gestureState.moveX })


        // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}
        // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
        // gestureState.d{x,y}
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // this.setState({ isGrabbing: false });

        // The user has released all touches while this view is the
        // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // this.setState({ isGrabbing: false });

        // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
        // should be cancelled
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
        // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.
        return true;
      },
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ shapesArr: getShapes()})
  }

  render() {
    const { shapesArr, isGrabbing } = this.state;

    const renderShape = ( shape, i ) => (
      <Image 
        key={`${shape.name}${i}`} 
        style={style.shapeImg} 
        source={shape.activeImg} 
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers} 
      >
    )
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        {isGrabbing && (
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              { 
                position: 'absolute',
                zIndex: 2, 
                top: this.point.y,
                left: this.point.x,
              }]}
          >
            {renderShape({ id: 2, name: 'star', activeImg: starImg }, 2)}
          </Animated.View> 
        )}
        <View style={style.selectionContainer}>
          {shapesArr.map((shape, i) => renderShape(shape, i))}
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to answer my own question. How I solved my problem was quite simple. I passed in the data (an object) as a prop into each `<Image />` component like so: `<Image shape={shape} />`. After injecting the component with the prop, I then go to `onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState)` and find in `memoizedProps` (`evt._targetInst.memoizedProps.shape`). Once I have the data I'm looking for, I update the state with it.

Comment: @Jeremy wow glad I as able to help! And sorry for the late response... I just saw this.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the image into a screen and use panResponder function with this screen.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! 
@Thanh Cao, can you please be a little more specific about what you mean, "split the image into a screen and use panResponder with this screen"?

Comment: I mean use one for each image.
Split each image into its own component and use each panResponder function with it

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ImageCustom extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({....})
    }
    render(){
     const {source, style} = this.props
     return(
       <Image source={source} style={style} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers} />
     )     
   }
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  const renderShape = ( shape, i ) => (
      <ImageCustom 
        key={`${shape.name}${i}`} 
        style={style.shapeImg} 
        source={shape.activeImg} 
      >
    )
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Thanh Cao, I appreciate the time you took to explain your answer. I will try it myself. I did also find a different way to solve this issue. It's not as elegant as yours but I will post it here as an answer. Once I've tried both and determine which one is better (as for performance, readability, and best practice).